# Is it safer to have a authentication/authrorization microservice?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, microservices, loopbackjs

My application has a microservice architecture. Right now I have implemented JWT into my "backend" microservice. But I was wondering to add authentication and authroization into a different microservices. I dont know if this is safer or what the security risks are?

Does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to have a different microservice for authntication and authorization.. This would be esp. very useful if in future you would have many applications and want to have SSO ( single sign on ) so all applications can call this microservice. This is how it is done everywhere.

If u are aware of suppose AWS; they have 100's of services and whenever we call api of these services those requests should be authenticated. Hence, they have a single service IAM for this.